# Spec of $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Find open sets and points of $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})[x])$.

My idea looks like this: let $i:\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{6Z} \hookrightarrow  \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}[x]$. It induces $i^*: \text{Spec}((\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}))[x] \rightarrow \text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})$. We know that prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ are of form $2\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ or $3\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. Now, I don't know how this corresponds to prime ideals in this polynomial ring. I don't want solution, but any hint. Maybe my idea is not good idea.

Comment: $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z = \mathbb F_2\times \mathbb F_3$ is the direct product of two fields.

Comment: I don't see at this moment how this could help in this exercise. It reduces to product of polynomial over field?

Comment: The formation of the polynomial ring commutes with finite direct products. And you should know somethins about the spectrum of a direct product of rings, don't you?

Comment: Could you write a solution? I don't know why, but I have a trouble :(

Answer (score 7):

Here a few steps:

1. $(\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z)[X]=(\mathbb F_2 \times \mathbb F_3)[X] = \mathbb F_2[X] \times \mathbb F_3[X]$.
2. $\operatorname{Spec}(R \times R') = \operatorname{Spec} R \sqcup \operatorname{Spec}R'$
3. You should be able to describe the open subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$, where $k$ is a field.
4. If you understand the open subsets of two topological spaces $X,Y$, you should also understand the open subsets of their disjoint union. An open subset of $X \sqcup Y$ is just the union of an open subset of $X$ and an open subset of $Y$.

I think you can go from here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It is now very clear.